# which one is correct, whine or whining as a noun?

Tags: difference, nouns, exam-questions

Do you think these 2 are correct?

> Cannot tolerate your whine anymore
>
> Cannot tolerate your whining anymore

I feel more comfortable using "whining" in this example but I can also see that "whine" is a noun too so it could also be correct?

Answer (score 1):

You would normally mean "whining".  A "whine" is complaining cry. But it is singular.  Once it has finished it has gone.

On the other hand, "whining" is a gerund, meaning the act of making whines. It is certainly possible to find someone's whining intolerable.  So while both are grammatically correct, the intended meaning is probably "whining".